# How to Zoom Out on a shockwave flash object C# Windows form

Tags: c#

I am using a Windows form in C# Visual Studio 2015 and I have a Shockwave Flash object built into it. How can I zoom out on this like what you would see in a browser when you press Ctrl + mousewheel?

My code:

```
public Main()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SWF.WMode = "Direct";
    SWF.Movie = @gameSWF;
    SWF.Play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So far from what I tried to do the same thing, however, it looks like axShockwave Flash Object can only be zoomed by being a child of a WebBrowser object. I gave up after 2 hours playing with Scale, Zoom, and ScaleMode.